# Magento 1.8 - Shipping cost change depending on products in cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I know I should have at least attempted something before asking a question here, but I genuinely have no idea where to start.

I have my shipping rates set up and don't want these to change. They are calculated based on the destination country.

What I want to do is keep to these rules except for when the cart contains ONLY items from a certain category. It would be a flat cost regardless of destination:

```
If CART contains ONLY category_id_916 THEN shipping = 2.99
ELSE follow normal rules
```

Where inside Magento would I look to implement some code like this? It could be after the system has already calculated the shipping cost if that is easier, as I can't imagine perfomance being affected too badly.  This way it would just overwrite the calculated cost with 2.99 if applicable.

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Tablerates for your cost caclulation. A good way to start is to check `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate` class.

`collectRates()` function is the one that interests you most. It contains `$request->getAllItems()` to iterate products and `$method->setPrice(...)` to set shipping price. So you can create your own logic about products (and of course their categories) and related shipping costs.

PS. Please kindly consider:

Never edit a magento core file! You can always overwrite it to local or (even better) create a small module that extends its functionality!

Hope I gave you an idea where to start digging :)